# Remote Mysql in EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I have a MySql server instance in Amazon EC2. In `my.cnf`

If I write `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` , server can starts.

But If I write `bind-address = SERVER_IP`, it gives Bind error.

So to connect this server remotely (because I want to use it for development in my local workspace), what should I do?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you're running MySQL on EC2 rather than using [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind to address 0.0.0.0. This makes MySQL listen on every IP.

**BUT** keep in mind that you might have to GRANT usage to the IP you are connecting from like

```
GRANT USAGE ON databse.table TO 'username'@'host';
```

Just as a small sidenote: You could use [Amazon Relational Database Service](http://aws.amazon.com/de/rds/) if you just want to have a MySQL database in the cloud

Answer (score 6):

I'll take a guess that `SERVER_IP` is the public (elastic?) IP of your instance.  That won't work, because from the machine's point of view, you only get an address in 10/8, and that private IP address is NATed by Amazon's network into the public IP you know and love.

You'll have to set `bind-address = 10.x.y.z` (or `0.0.0.0`, as Christopher Perrin suggests) to make it work.  Remember, though, that a database server open to the world is a delicious target of opportunity...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is create a secure link between you and the database instance, as through OpenVPN or similar. OpenVPN may be overkill but it would be best. This way you can bind to its tun0 interface and not have to worry about nagging little things like getting hacked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your current IP to the security-group your server is using.

1. Got to http://ping.eu
2. Copy your IP address and add it to the security-group (usually is default). Somthing like this: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32